# Not able to connect to Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded the recent version of Eclipse Mars. Now I am trying to connect to Eclipse Marketplace. But not able to do so. I am getting the following below stack trace:

[image: Stack Trace Details Here]

Comment: Perhaps the website is temporarily down. It happens, even to stackoverflow.

Comment: Provide the whole Exception Stack Trace. It contains more information.